# GeoPandas: plot two layers but only to the extent of the smaller one

Tags: python, geopandas, matplotlib

I am using GeoPandas and I want to plot two layers. I want the map to have the extent of the smaller layer. With this code below, the map's size automatically fits the bigger layer.

```
import geopandas as gp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from shapely.geometry import LineString
from shapely.geometry import MultiPoint

thesmallpoints=gp.GeoDataFrame([[MultiPoint([(0, 0), (1, 1), (1,2), (2,2)])]],columns=['geometry'])
thelargeline=gp.GeoDataFrame([[LineString([(0, 0), (1, 1), (1,2), (20,20)])]],columns=['geometry'])

base=thesmallpoints.plot(marker='o', color='blue', markersize=20)
thelargeline.plot(ax=base, color='green')
plt.show()
```

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set limits to the axis without chaining original GDF.

```
import geopandas as gp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from shapely.geometry import LineString, MultiPoint, Polygon

thesmallpoints=gp.GeoDataFrame([[MultiPoint([(0, 0), (1, 1), (1,2), (2,2)])]],columns=['geometry'])
thelargeline=gp.GeoDataFrame([[LineString([(0, 0), (1, 1), (1,2), (20,20)])]],columns=['geometry'])

minx, miny, maxx, maxy = thesmallpoints.geometry.total_bounds


f, ax = plt.subplots()
thesmallpoints.plot(ax=ax, marker='o', color='blue', markersize=20)
thelargeline.plot(ax=ax, color='green')
ax.set_xlim(minx - .1, maxx + .1) # added/substracted value is to give some margin around total bounds
ax.set_ylim(miny - .1, maxy + .1)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

So I solved the problem by clipping the large linestring as follows

```
import geopandas as gp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from shapely.geometry import LineString, MultiPoint, Polygon

thesmallpoints=gp.GeoDataFrame([[MultiPoint([(0, 0), (1, 1), (1,2), (2,2)])]],columns=['geometry'])
thelargeline=gp.GeoDataFrame([[LineString([(0, 0), (1, 1), (1,2), (20,20)])]],columns=['geometry'])
minx, miny, maxx, maxy = thesmallpoints.geometry.total_bounds
thesmallpointsenvelope = gp.GeoDataFrame([[Polygon([(minx, miny), (minx, maxy), (maxx, maxy), (maxx,miny), (minx, miny)])]], columns=['geometry'])
thelargeline = thelargeline.intersection(thesmallpointsenvelope.unary_union)
base=thesmallpoints.plot(marker='o', color='blue', markersize=20)
thelargeline.plot(ax=base, color='green')
plt.show()
```